# No versions could be resolved for groupid.artifactid error when using Repository Connector

Tags: maven, jenkins

I want to simply download a war file from a Nexus repo and deploy it on a remote tomcat server.
I found this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin, which seems to help me do the same.

I have the following configuration:

[image]

In hue-central, I have correctly configured the repo url.
If I open `<repo url>/com/worksap/company/hue-interface-front` in my browser, I can see all the versions along with `maven-metadata.xml`, which contains all the versions.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try running it? I do not trust error messages shown in the UI anymore (not especially _these_ ones).

Comment: What's the nexus version?

Answer (score 0):

Try following: Go to Jenkins Administration / System configuration, find the Artifact Resolver section, and check Repo Type of your repository. If it is empty, set it to "default". It was causing the same problem in my case.
[Example here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyNsg.png)